# nofollow links on jQuery interaction

Tags: seo, google, jquery, nofollow

Is it important to use `rel="nofollow"` on jQuery interaction links?

`<a href="#" rel="nofollow">jQuery interaction link</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. "Nofollow" provides a way for webmasters to tell search engines "Don't follow links on this page" or "Don't follow this specific link." Since that link isn't an actual hyperlink but a JavaScript trigger, there's no need to use nofollow on it.

Generally speaking, nofollow should be used on the following type of links:

- Untrusted content
- Paid links

Comment: You can also use nofollow for Crawl prioritization on internal link you do not wish Google to be indexing, such as 'sign in links, 'print page links' etc, as mentioned on thier help page: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569